# UITableViewController loadView loaded the "2-view-3" nib but didn't get a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView dropped onto it in IB.  It builds fine but when I run it it crashes with the error:

> [UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "2-view-3" nib but didn't get a UITableView

I am using Storyboards. My view is a UIViewController not a UITableViewController but somewhere it seems to expect that it is loading a UITableViewController.  In IB I set the class for the UIViewController to be my custom UIViewController class which is of type UIViewController.

Code I am trying to make work in my project is here: https://github.com/daria-kopaliani/DAContextMenuTableViewController

But it uses a UITableViewController.  My project uses a UIViewController with a UITableView in it.  The IB hierarchy for the demo project is as below:

[image]

But I have mine as follows:

[image]

The top of my .h of my custom UIViewController looks as follows:

[image: UIViewController snapshot]

Not sure if I can use the above project with anything other than a UITableViewController but that is what I am trying to do.

UPDATE:

```
 (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refresh) name:@"refreshTable" object:nil];

[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];

[self initializeDateFormatter];
[self initializeTimeFormatter];

if (self.managedObjectContext == nil) {
    self.managedObjectContext = [[MVCoreDataController sharedInstance] newManagedObjectContext];
}

self.tblList.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.tblList.dataSource = self;
self.myNavBar.delegate = self;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
```

UPDATE 2 (adding interface for MVContextMenuTableViewController):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MVContextMenuCell.h"
#import "MVOverlayView.h"


@interface MVContextMenuTableViewController : UITableViewController <MVContextMenuCellDelegate, MVOverlayViewDelegate,     UITableViewDelegate>

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) MVContextMenuCell *cellDisplayingMenuOptions;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL shouldDisableUserInteractionWhileEditing;

- (void)hideMenuOptionsAnimated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

What does this error mean and how can I track it down?

Comment: Can you post the code that tries to instantiate your custom vc?  Or is it trying to get loaded on a segue?

Comment: @danh do you mean the init for my custom UIViewController?

Comment: I was thinking the code that triggers the presentation of the vc.

Comment: The VC with the UITableView on it is presented as my root view controller when the app launches - in didFinishLaunchWithOptions there is nothing but return YES.  Not sure what code you're asking for but I can update the post with viewDidLoad method too.

Comment: What's the interface for `MVContextMenuTableViewController` look like?

Comment: I updated the original question with the MVContextMenuTableViewController.  The problem is likely that this expects a UITableViewController but I have a UIViewController with a UITableView added to it.

Answer (score 1):

You say you have a `UIViewController` but in reality a `MVViewController` is a type of `UITableViewController` through two levels of inheritance.

Assuming you've made the class of `mainVC` in your storyboard to be a `MVViewController`, then its need to have a table view as its primary view is legitimate.

It seems like you need to change `@interface MVContextMenuTableViewController : UITableViewController...` into `@interface MVContextMenuTableViewController : UIViewController...`.

Comment: This was helpful but when I made that change there are errors in the MVContextMenuTableViewController.m file because it references a UITableView called tableView as the primary view in the hierarchy - my custom table view - tblGoalsList - cannot be referenced in MVContextMenuTableViewController.

Comment: Obviously I don't know what's inside `MVContextMenuTableViewController`, so I have no idea if this will work but...what if you connect the `tableView` outlet to your `UITableView` subview?  (For that matter, maybe you should have `@interface MVViewController:UIViewController...` if you're having trouble with the superclass.)

Comment: You were correct with that last comment.  I changed the MIViewController back to being a UIViewController and fixed a few other issues that I had with the hierarchy in IB and it is now working.  Thank you very much for your help.